# Is this Solution for Caches vs Cookies Going to Get Me in Trouble?

Tags: jquery, cache, cookies, plugin-w3-total-cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I've come up with a provisional solution for a not exactly common, but far from unprecedented problem with the interaction of popular WP caching solutions with cookies, in this case the standard WP comment cookies. My solution also bears on the rarely well-defined "known users" exception to serving cached files. Whether it's usable or not, I figure that explaining it and possibly learning why it's a bad idea might be generally instructive.

I've tested my method with WP Super Cache, W3 Total Cache, and Comet Cache. The one that I broke down for myself in detail while studying this problem was WP Super Cache ("WPSC" hereafter), so I'll use it as my main example.

### BACKGROUND

When a WP standard comment thread is set to allow visitors to comment, comments cookies are set for any commenter who is not a registered user and logged in, with actual commenting privileges subjected to further checks. In what I believe is the most common configuration, a commenter needs to supply only a name and an email address. These are stored within two browser cookies, usually `comment_author_ . COOKIEHASH`, and `comment_author_email_ . COOKIEHASH`. `COOKIEHASH` is defined according to user options.

If set to deliver freshly generated files to "known users," WPSC determines whether or not to serve a cached file on the basis of several checks: Logged-in users get fresh files, and so do visitors "who can comment." The latter are chiefly identified by the presence in their browsers of `comment_author_` cookies which are not specifically or uniquely identified for the particular user by the `COOKIEHASH` (usually but not always an MD5-encoded version of the "siteurl" recorded in site options).

What appears to be the key part of the WPSC code, from wp-cache-phase1.php LL371-383, uses a RegEx pattern to get a string, cycling through the cookies:

```
$regex = "/^wp-postpass|^comment_author_";
if ( defined( 'LOGGED_IN_COOKIE' ) )
    $regex .= "|^" . preg_quote( constant( 'LOGGED_IN_COOKIE' ) );
else
    $regex .= "|^wordpress_logged_in_";
$regex .= "/";
while ($key = key($_COOKIE)) {
    if ( preg_match( $regex, $key ) ) {
        wp_cache_debug( "wp_cache_get_cookies_values: $regex Cookie detected: $key", 5 );
        $string .= $_COOKIE[ $key ] . ",";
    }
    next($_COOKIE);
}
```

Now, if I were working strictly in PHP, I could re-produce or hook into WP core functions, and get the normal `comment_author_ . COOKIEHASH` set by the comment template, but I am working in jQuery using the jQuery Cookie plug-in. However, as you can see if you look at the RegEx, the WPSC function doesn't care about the `COOKIEHASH`: It's satisfied if it encounters `comment_author_`.

### MY TENTATIVE SOLUTION

`$.cookie( 'comment_author_proxyhash', 'proxy_author', { path: '/' } );`

For those unfamiliar with jQuery Cookie: The above sets a simple session cookie with key = `comment_author_proxyhash` and value = `proxy_author`, good for the entire site. (Also, for those who use jQuery Cookie and WP, in addition to pre-substituting the familiar jQuery `$` for the WP `jQuery`, I've also already set `$.cookie.raw = true;`.)

I added the line to my jQuery script, and, *voila!*, WPSC, W3 Total Cache, and Comet Cache are all acting like I want them to. After I use the script, and reload, I get fresh pages. If I happen to place a real comment, the normal `comment_author_` and `comment_author_email_` cookies are set, and there doesn't seem to be any problem with co-existence.

Perhaps one defect would be that the "proxyhash" cookie will travel with the user as long as he or she keeps the session open, but that doesn't strike me as likely a major problem - or even worth a warning. I've certainly never heard of someone complaining about such a thing happening with one of the regular cookies.

But maybe there's something I'm missing, and about to discover much to my woe, if potentially to my edification as well. Or maybe there's a relatively simple best-practicey way for me to replicate the `COOKIEHASH` in jQuery, also covering alternative use cases... or to achieve the same end effect by other means - other ways of tricking the caching plug-ins into treating the visitor as a commenter...

If not, is there any good reason NOT to push this or something close to it out to the universe in a plug-in?

Comment: Props for a well researched and documented question. However, I feel the nature of the question might open this to more of a discussion as opposed to a definitive answer (off-topic: primarily opinion based). FWIW in my opinion I see nothing wrong here - ultimately you're just setting a single, generic cookie with no personal data.

Comment: Thanks much for the input. I'd be grateful for such a discussion, and I'd mark as good answers any that a) pointed out a problem with this "generic cookie" method, b) provided alternative means for achieving the same effect, or c) provided useful insight into underlying technical questions relating to "known users."

Comment: Just to note, you could use `wp_localize_script` to pass the cookie hash to your Javascript so that you could use the "native" cookie instead of the proxyhash. Otherwise, this is a very interesting issue and your solution seems solid, although cookies + cache are always so complex it's hard to say if it's "the right" solution or if there's something being missed. Great research!

Comment: Interesting question - I can't think of anything about this that would get you into trouble, but can I ask why you want to bypass the cache in this way? Giving users this ability kind of defeats the purpose of having the full page cache to begin with. Further, an extra cookie adds to the request size (albeit minimally), when the same result can be achieved with common cache configurations by simply appending any query params to the URL, e.g. mysite.com?a. Just my $0.02...

Comment: ssnepenthe: Maybe I should have explained: A plugin I was developing when I wrote the question - https://wordpress.org/plugins/commenter-ignore-button/ - uses jQuery to allow visitors to put selected commenters "on ignore." The initial action applies CSS formatting to the comment thread, and then relies on a cookie to store the designation and its presence to duplicate the effect (via PHP) over subsequent refreshes until cookie expiration. In a cached version of the page, the effect wouldn't be registered. So, yes, it's a form of intentional localized cache-busting.

Comment: @CKMacLeod Makes sense - I still don't see any technical problems with this approach, but I can imagine some users being frustrated when they realize cache is bypassed... Maybe it would be possible to handle 100% via JS without touching cache? E.g. on DOM content loaded, scan the full list of comments and collapse/hide/remove any that the user has chosen to ignore.

Comment: In my experience with most WP sites, once your browser has cached files, a lot of the work of site-level caching is done, but I believe it's true that the user will lose some caching benefits at the site in question (like any logged-in user or active commenter under "recognized" exceptions) Someday, I may do some more systematic comparisons some day, and think about the "pure Java" option and reasons I decided on the hybrid Java + PHP approach when working on the app.Thanks for the input (with a bit more detail I might have graded it a good "answer"!)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with comment_author_proxyhash cookie will of course technically work - all caching plugins I know doesn't analyze hash value and will just stop delivery of cached content based on comment_author_* cookie presense.

Problem here is that page caching functionality is something websites really need and often page caching is configured exactly because naked WordPress performance is not enough and able to even crash server at peak times. It depends on website content nature, but site owners sometimes just not able to pay for hardware required to handle everything via PHP/WP code.
In other words as much as possible traffic has to be served from page cache whenever possible.
From practice I may tell that we often have to identify and disable plugins doing cache exceptions.

Of course it's not always possible, but try to work with cached page whenever possible. For example you may hide `div` tags with comments you want to ignore via javascript, or ajax-ify whole comments block.

In any case you don't need to mark visitor as a commenter, but stop caching because of your custom logic reasons. So it's better to use unique cookie and make it a cache exception signal.
W3 Total Cache has "Reject cookies" option for that, but not other plugins from your list so you'll need a hack like one you have suggested.

Comment: Thanks! You raise a number of valid issues, but I'll say that what this code does, essentially, is treat any visitor who is participating in the comment threads enough to put someone "on ignore" or "mute" as a "known user/commenter." If a site can't handle such participation, then it probably can't handle a standard WordPress comment template (and commenting community) either!

Comment: Think you are right here, while of course can't know for sure how your users use it. Btw many high traffic websites offload their comments processing to a separate requests or even third-party service exactly for the purpose of displaying article content fast and lazy load dynamic comments content later. Take it as an offtopic idea for maybe further versions of your plugin :)